# Stay connect to a voice channel

Tags: python, discord.py

I use this to join my bot to channel but it dc after few hours. I want it to stay in channel 24/7.

```
@client.command(aliases=['j'])
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def join(ctx):
    connected = ctx.author.voice
    await ctx.message.delete()
    timenow = time.strftime("%H:%M")
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Joined the VC", color=0x2bff00)
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.message.author} | {timenow}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if not connected:
        await ctx.send("You need to be connected in a voice channel to use this command!")
        return
    global vc
    vc = await connected.channel.connect()
```

Comment: is it doing anything? Or is it being disconnected due to no activity?

Comment: no it just connects to voice .

Comment: then what's the point. I tried searching for a similar issue, but couldn't find it. It's possible, that either discord or discord.py has integrated innactivity detection -> disconnect. It might also just be your internet.

Comment: server uptime is 99%.Bot shows server members on username so I want it to connect to a channel but idk why it get dc

Comment: isn't it better to use a separate locked channel for this? No issues with voice channels

Comment: You mean show members count on a channel name? its ok but I thought that looks cooler :D

Comment: yes, I've seen servers that do that - create a new channel just to display the count.